# How to propogate an exception from tcp outbound gateway to upstream SI components

Tags: spring, exception, spring-integration

I have been searching over the internet and have been trying different ways to make it work but I couldn't get it working.

Actually my system need to connect to multiple tcp server endpoints (which we call payers endpoint) as a tcp client application. The client components include the throttling and queuing components and they get initialized dynamically based on the payers configurations stored in DB as a separate application context. I have created a tcp outbound gateway for this purpose and which is being initialized in a dynamic context based on the ideas given in

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/advanced

What I want is to catch/get exceptions to the calling code at the time calling the payersGateway component in case of any error. But I am unable to receive the exceptions back.

My context file for tcp client connectivity is as follow:

### dynamic-tcp-gateway-context file

```
<context:property-placeholder/>

<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="client"
                               type="client"
                               host="${host}"
                               port="${port}"
                               single-use="true"
                               so-timeout="${soTimeout}"
                               serializer="byteArrayLfSerializer"
                               deserializer="ediTcpSerializer"
/>

<bean id="ediTcpSerializer" class="com.abc.throttling.EdiTcpSerializer">
    <property name="maxMessageSize" value="20480000"/>
</bean>
<bean id="byteArrayLfSerializer" class="org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.serializer.ByteArrayLfSerializer">
    <property name="maxMessageSize" value="20480000"/>
</bean>


<int:channel id="toPayerChannel">
    <int:dispatcher task-executor="producerThreadExecutor"/>
</int:channel>
<task:executor id="producerThreadExecutor" pool-size="10" queue-capacity="50" rejection-policy="ABORT"/>


<int:channel id="throttlerChannel">
    <int:priority-queue capacity="${queueSize:1000}"/> <!-- for example queue size, you can increase this capacity
    based on your
    requirement -->
</int:channel>

<int:bridge input-channel="toPayerChannel" output-channel="throttlerChannel" />


 <int-ip:tcp-outbound-gateway id="outGateway"
                             request-channel="throttlerChannel"
                             connection-factory="client"
                             request-timeout="10000"
                             reply-timeout="${replyTimeout}">

    <int:poller id="tcpPoller" error-channel="errorChannel" fixed-rate="1000" max-messages-per-poll="${messageRate:20}"/>

</int-ip:tcp-outbound-gateway>


<int:transformer input-channel="errorChannel"
                 ref="exceptionTransformer" method="createErrorResponse"/>


<bean id="exceptionTransformer" class="com.stella.healthenet.throttling.TcpGatewayExceptionTransformer"/>


<int:object-to-string-transformer input-channel="errorChannel"/>
```

application context for main payers connectivity is as follow:

### main-payers-gateway-context file

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.abc.throttling" />

class="com.abc.throttling.DynamicTcpChannelResolverTest" id="dynamicTcpChannelResolverTest"/>-->

<int:gateway id="payersGateway"
             service-interface="com.abc.gateway.PayersGateway"
             default-request-channel="toDynRouter"
default-request-timeout="1000000"
default-reply-timeout="${payersGateway.defaultReplyTimout}"
/>


<int:converter ref="converter"/>
<bean class="com.abc.manager.edi.core.core4.ByteArrayToStringConverter" id="converter"/>

<int:converter ref="converter2"/>
<bean class="com.abc.manager.edi.core.core2.Core2RealTimeResponseToString" id="converter2"/>

<int:converter ref="converter3"/>
<bean class="com.abc.manager.edi.core.core4.Core4RealTimeResponseToString" id="converter3"/>

<int:channel id="toDynRouter" />

<int:router  resolution-required="true" input-channel="toDynRouter"
            expression="@dynamicPayerChannelResolver.resolve(headers['payer'])"  >
</int:router>
```

The code for dynamic channel resolver is as follow:

```
@Component("dynamicPayerChannelResolver")
public class DynamicPayerChannelResolver {

@Value("${throttling.payersChannelQueueSize}")
private String payersChannelQueueSize;

@Value("${throttling.tcpSoTimeout}")
private String tcpSoTimeout;

@Value("${tcpOutboundGateway.replyTimeout}")
private String tcpReplyTimeout;

@Autowired
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;



public static final int MAX_CACHE_SIZE = 30;

private static final org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger();

@Autowired
PayerRepositoryService payerRepositoryService;

private final Map<UUID, MessageChannel> channels = Collections.synchronizedMap(new LinkedHashMap<UUID,
        MessageChannel>(){

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            protected boolean removeEldestEntry(
                    Entry<UUID, MessageChannel> eldest) {
                //This returning true means the least recently used
                //channel and its application context will be closed and removed
                boolean remove = size() > MAX_CACHE_SIZE;
                if(remove) {
                    MessageChannel channel = eldest.getValue();
                    ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = contexts.get(channel);
                    if(ctx != null) { //shouldn't be null ideally
                        ctx.close();
                        contexts.remove(channel);
                    }
                }
                return remove;
            }

        });


private final Map<MessageChannel, ConfigurableApplicationContext> contexts =
        new HashMap<MessageChannel, ConfigurableApplicationContext>();



/**
 * Resolve a payer to a channel, where each payer gets a private
 * application context and the channel is the inbound channel to that
 * application context.
 *
 * @param payer
 * @return a channel
 */
public MessageChannel resolve(UUID payer) {
    MessageChannel channel = this.channels.get(payer);
    if (channel == null) {
        channel = createNewPayerChannel(payerRepositoryService.findPayerByPayerId(payer));
    }
    return channel;
}



private synchronized MessageChannel createNewPayerChannel(PayerEntity payer) {
    MessageChannel channel = this.channels.get(payer.getPayerId());
    if (channel == null) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx;

        if(TransportType.SOAP_WSDL.getValue().equals(payer.getConnTransportType())){
            ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                    new String[] { "dynamic-soap-gateway-context.xml" },
                    false,applicationContext);
        }
        else{
            ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                    new String[] { "dynamic-tcp-gateway-context.xml" },
                    false,applicationContext);
        }


        this.setEnvironmentForPayer(ctx, payer);
        ctx.refresh();
        channel = ctx.getBean("toPayerChannel", MessageChannel.class);
        this.channels.put(payer.getPayerId(), channel);
        //Will works as the same reference is presented always
        this.contexts.put(channel, ctx);

    }
    return channel;
}


public void updatePollerConfigs() {

    Iterator it = this.channels.entrySet().iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        PayerEntity payer = this.payerRepositoryService.findPayerByPayerId((UUID)pair.getKey());
        final String transportType = payer.getConnTransportType();


        if(TransportType.SOAP_WSDL.getValue().equals(transportType)){

            MessageChannel channel= this.channels.get(payer);
            ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx;
            ctx=this.contexts.get(channel);
            PollingConsumer pc = ctx.getBean("soapPoller",PollingConsumer.class);
            //TODO: this value need to be set from payer configs in db.
            pc.setMaxMessagesPerPoll(10);

        }
        else if (TransportType.X12_SOCKET.getValue().equals(transportType)) {

            MessageChannel channel= this.channels.get(payer);
            ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx;
            ctx=this.contexts.get(channel);
            PollingConsumer pc = ctx.getBean("outGateway",PollingConsumer.class);
            //TODO: this value need to be set from payer configs in db.
            pc.setMaxMessagesPerPoll(10);
        }
    }
}


private void setEnvironmentForPayer(ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx,
                                    PayerEntity payer) {

    final String transportType = payer.getConnTransportType();
    final String endPoint = payer.getConnEndPoint();

    if(payer.getMessageRate()==null){

        throw new NullPointerException("MessageRate value is NULL in DB. Please specify a MessageRate value in " +
                "Payers DB for PayerID: " + payer.getPayerId());
    }


    final String messageRate = payer.getMessageRate();


    StandardEnvironment env = new StandardEnvironment();

    Properties props = new Properties();


    // populate properties for payer
    ;
    if(TransportType.SOAP_WSDL.getValue().equals(transportType)){
        props.setProperty("endpoint", endPoint);
        props.setProperty("messageRate",messageRate);
        props.setProperty("queueSize",payersChannelQueueSize);

    }
    else if (TransportType.X12_SOCKET.getValue().equals(transportType)) {
        if (!endPoint.contains(":")) {

            throw new Exception(ErrorType.UNEXPECTED, "Payer X12 Socket endpoint must include a port.");
        }

        final String ip;
        if (endPoint.contains("/")) {
            ip = endPoint.substring(endPoint.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, endPoint.lastIndexOf(":"));
        } else {
            ip = endPoint.substring(0, endPoint.lastIndexOf(":"));

        }

        final String port = endPoint.substring(endPoint.lastIndexOf(':') + 1);

        props.setProperty("host", ip);
        props.setProperty("port", port);
        props.setProperty("messageRate",messageRate);
        props.setProperty("queueSize",payersChannelQueueSize);
        props.setProperty("soTimeout", tcpSoTimeout);
        props.setProperty("replyTimeout",tcpReplyTimeout);
    }


    PropertiesPropertySource pps = new PropertiesPropertySource("payerChannelProps", props);
    env.getPropertySources().addLast(pps);
    ctx.setEnvironment(env);
}
```

I want to get the exceptions generated at the downstream components to appear at the payersGateway interface send method call i.e., shown below:

```
String response = payersGateway.send(
            MessageBuilder.withPayload(requestMessage)
                    .setHeader("endpointUrl", endPoint)
                    .setHeader("senderId", coreSenderId)
                    .setHeader("receiverId", payerIdCode)
                    .setHeader("username", username)
                    .setHeader("password", password)
                    .setHeader("payloadType", payloadType)
                    .setHeader("nginxUrl", nginxUrl)
                    .setHeader("payer", payerId)
                    .setHeader("transType", transType)
                    .setHeader("priority", 1)
                    .build());
```

where the payersGateway is simple interface pointing to Gateway component in main context file.

```
public interface PayersGateway {
public String send(Message<String> message);
```

}

Please see the stack trace of produced exception as below:

```
 [task-scheduler-1] ERROR org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpOutboundGateway - Tcp Gateway exception
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
    at javax.net.DefaultSocketFactory.createSocket(SocketFactory.java:271)
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetClientConnectionFactory.createSocket(TcpNetClientConnectionFactory.java:76)
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetClientConnectionFactory.buildNewConnection(TcpNetClientConnectionFactory.java:49)
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.AbstractClientConnectionFactory.obtainNewConnection(AbstractClientConnectionFactory.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.AbstractClientConnectionFactory.obtainConnection(AbstractClientConnectionFactory.java:79)
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.AbstractClientConnectionFactory.getConnection(AbstractClientConnectionFactory.java:69)
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpOutboundGateway.handleRequestMessage(TcpOutboundGateway.java:130)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.PollingConsumer.handleMessage(PollingConsumer.java:129)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:272)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.access$000(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:58)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:190)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:186)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:353)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:51)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:344)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[task-scheduler-1] ERROR org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler - org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to send or receive; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpOutboundGateway.handleRequestMessage(TcpOutboundGateway.java:158)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.PollingConsumer.handleMessage(PollingConsumer.java:129)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:272)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.access$000(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:58)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:190)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:186)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:353)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:51)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:344)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:81)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
    at javax.net.DefaultSocketFactory.createSocket(SocketFactory.java:271)
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetClientConnectionFactory.createSocket(TcpNetClientConnectionFactory.java:76)
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetClientConnectionFactory.buildNewConnection(TcpNetClientConnectionFactory.java:49)
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.AbstractClientConnectionFactory.obtainNewConnection(AbstractClientConnectionFactory.java:116)
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.AbstractClientConnectionFactory.obtainConnection(AbstractClientConnectionFactory.java:79)
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.AbstractClientConnectionFactory.getConnection(AbstractClientConnectionFactory.java:69)
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpOutboundGateway.handleRequestMessage(TcpOutboundGateway.java:130)
    ... 21 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work as you need; exceptions before the `throttlerChannel` will be thrown directly to the caller; exceptions after that channel will be sent to the gateway by the poller's error handler.

Perhaps your gateway timeout is too short?

Turning on DEBUG logging and following the message flow should help you debug it.

**EDIT**

You can fix the missing `failedMessage` by adding a bean of this type to the Tcp outbound gateway's `<int-ip:request-handler-advice-chain />`...

```
public class FailedMessagePopulator extends AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice {

    @Override
    protected Object doInvoke(ExecutionCallback callback, Object target, Message<?> message) throws Exception {
        try {
            return callback.execute();
        }
        catch (MessagingException e) {
            if (e.getFailedMessage() == null) {
                throw new MessageHandlingException(message, e.getMessage(), e);
            }
            else {
                throw e;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw new MessageHandlingException(message, e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

}
```

Note that you will need to add the error channel to the `<gateway/>` since the poller will now see the failed message and send the exception back to the gateway for error handling.

Comment: Hi, timeout is not short. based on your suggestion, I tried to investigate what coming as an exception. In the TcpGatewayExceptionTransformer (please see the edited code in dynamic-tcp-context file) class I observed that the failedMessage property of MessagingException is null. I think that is why I cannot get my exception back to caller. Please help how can I fix it.

Comment: Edit the question to show the full stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Just added the stack trace of the exception that is not reached back to caller. (please see the edited section). I am using 4.3.13.RELEASE of spring integration.

Comment: This is a bug; it was recently fixed in 5.0.5 [INT-4421](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4421). If you can use a direct channel instead of the queue channel (perhaps with an async gateway) it should solve it; if not, I can provide a work-around. With the 5.0 fix, the error channel goes on the gateway, not the poller; the null failedMessage prevents the poller sending the failure to the gateway.

Comment: Thanks for reply Gary. Actually I have throttling requirement to implement and for that I had to use queue channel here. Is there any other possibility or workaround that you suggest to fix this. I would be greatful.